# Buttons/Lables are not showing up on the new window (Python tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

When I click the Tic Tac Toe Button, it is supposed to launch a new window which it does but doesn't display the buttons and doesn't give any error.

The two pieces of code are in two different scripts.

when I run Tic Tac Toe in its own script, it runs and displays all the buttons.

```
import tkinter as tk
import hangman
import playgame

class GAME_APP(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        container=tk.Frame(self)


        container.pack(side='top',fill='both',expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        F=StartPage

        frame = F(container, self)

        self.frames[F] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()



class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="GAME APP", font=('Ravie',50,'bold italic'),fg='Dark Blue',bg='Light Pink',padx=20,pady=10,justify='center')
        label.grid(padx=80,pady=50)


        button = tk.Button(self, text="Tic Tac Toe",bg='Light Green',fg='Purple',bd=8,justify='center',font=('Broadway',18,'bold italic'),command=self.TTT)
        button.grid(padx=30,pady=30)

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Hangman",bg='Light Green',fg='Purple',bd=8,justify='center',font=('Broadway',18,'bold italic'),command=self.hangman_win)
        button2.grid(padx=30,pady=30)

    def hangman_win(self):
        bb=hangman.mainwindow()

    def TTT(self):
        tt=playgame.GUI()

app=GAME_APP()
app.title('Game App')
app.geometry('700x500')
app.mainloop()
```

This is Tic Tac Toe's GUI (There were originally 9 buttons but removed them to keep code here short.)

```
class GUI(playGame):
    def __init__(self):    

        import tkinter as tk
        self.home=tk.Tk()
        self.home.title("Tic Tac Toe")
        self.home.geometry("160x300")
        w,h=6,3                      

        self.c1r1=tk.Button(text='',width=w, height=h, command=lambda: self.userTurn(self.c1r1))
        self.c1r1.pack()            

        self.c1r2=tk.Button(text='',width=w, height=h, command=lambda: self.userTurn(self.c1r2))
        self.c1r2.pack()


        self.announce=tk.Label(text='No winner yet',width=w, height=h)
        self.announce.pack()



        self.home.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the buttons and label have no `master` parameter. `master` refers to the parent window in which a widget will display.

For example. The first button:

```
self.c1r1=tk.Button(text='',width=w, height=h, ...)
```

You have defined this following the format `name, widget type, (options...)`.
With the name being `c1r1`, the widget type being `tk.Button` and the options being `text, width, height` etc...

However, the correct format for widgets is `name, widget type (master, options...)`.

As the parent window for the buttons was defined '`self.home=tk.Tk()`', this parent window needs to be referenced in place of the `master` parameter for any widgets defined in that window.

So taking that into account, your first button would now be defined as:

```
self.c1r1=tk.Button(self.home, text='',width=w, height=h, ...)
```

Make sure to add `self.home` to the other buttons and they will display.